# Changing the color of one character within a word without changing the kerning properties of the word?

Tags: html, css

Suppose we have the following element:

```
<div>STACKOVERFLOW</div>
```

And we want to make the `A` red, but without changing the kerning properties of the word.  In other words we want the word to display exactly the same way it did before.  There is a similar question here:

[change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css)

However using a `span` element changes the kerning properties of the word (Adds more space in front of the `A`).

Here's a screenshot from the jsfiddle in the [referenced SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css)

[image]

As you can see it looks like the `span` element adds a little more space.

### Update

I'll add a screenshot along with some code to show what I mean.  If you look at the word `ICON` in the screen shot it is marked up like this (And the spans are causing additional space to be added):

```
    <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">Ic</span>
    <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-pink-a200 u-font-weight-900">o</span>
    <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">n</span>
    <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-800 u-font-weight-100">Utility Tests</span></h1>
```

[image]

```css
div { font-size: 3em; background: blue; display: inline-block; }
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<div>STACKOVERFLOW</div>
<div>ST<span>A</span>CKOVERFLOW</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjnDF.png">
```

Per request in the comments color utilities come from [SuperflyCSS Color Utilities](https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-colors/target/test/html/)

The font utilities come from the [SuperflyCSS Font Utilities](https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-fonts/target/test/html/)

And the `u-text-uppercase` utility comes from The font utilities come from the [SuperflyCSS Format Utilities](https://github.com/superflycss/utilities-format)

### Another Update

Thanks you guys - The key - as mentioned in the accepted answer, is to keep the `<span>` elements on the same line.  When I do that is done this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, never noticed that before. https://jsfiddle.net/qLft5yt7/ Don't know if there is a way around this though, unless you want to start fiddling with negative margins and magic numbers ... maybe some of the more obscure/new/browser specific font rendering properties might be able to help in some way.

Comment: Have just tried @CBroe fiddle in Firefox and Chromium; noticed absolutely zero kerning: the two lines are pixel-for-pixel the same on my machine, even when adding a span to every character after the `A`.  Can you add a screenshot of this kerning issue?  I'm wondering if there are more than a few variables affecting the rendering ...

Comment: I'll post the links to the utility libraries being used.

Comment: @Ole without keeping `span` in one line it is also possible. but as you wish....:)

Comment: @ankitapatel you were right essentially in your first answer which had the spans on the same line.   Guys lots of great effort put into the answers here so please give them some upvote love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep it on one line!

You could use:

`<span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">Ic</span><span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-pink-a200 u-font-weight-900">o</span><span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">n</span><span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-800 u-font-weight-100">Utility Tests</span>`

or:

`<span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">Ic<span class="u-text-color-md-pink-a200">o</span>n</span>`

Or you could just use `font-size: 0` on parent & reset its children font-size or  use `float: left` and a `&nbsp;`

```css
.third {  font-size: 0;  }

.third span {  font-size: 16px;  }

.fourth span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<strong>First:</strong><br>
<span class="first">Ic<span>o</span>n</span> <span>Utility Tests</span>

<br><br>
<strong>Second:</strong><br>

<span class="second">
<span>Ic</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>Utility Tests</span>
</span>

<br><br>
<strong>Third:</strong><br>

<span class="third">
<span>Ic</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>n </span>
<span>Utility Tests</span>
</span>

<br><br>
<strong>Fourth:</strong><br>

<span class="fourth">
<span>Ic</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>n </span>
<span>&nbsp;Utility Tests</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @chrishappy (The user emoji says it all :) ) - I think it adds a tiny bit of space still, but it's not noticeable really in my demo - so we'll roll with it.  I posted my original experiment in the question so everyone can see roughly what could happen.

Comment: For my use case I don't think it's noticeable at all, but in the side by side JSFiddle, it doubles the original distance between the T and the A - but with negative margins and all other great answers here we should have this covered!  Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I think this should helpful for you. Please try this. To avoid extra space I have used `font-size:0` to `h1` tag because span tag have taken default property `display:inline-block`.

```css
h1{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:0;
}
.u-text-color-md-pink-a200{
  color:#FF4081;
}
.u-font-weight-900{
  font-weight:bold;
}
h1 span{
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">Ic</span>
  <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-pink-a200 u-font-weight-900">o</span>
  <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-900 u-font-weight-900">n</span>
  <span class="u-text-uppercase u-text-color-md-grey-800 u-font-weight-100">Utility Tests</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `<span>`, and apply a negative margin on it.

```css
#one{
  color:#ff0000;
}
#two{
  color:#ff0000;
  margin:0 -0.04em;
}
div { 
  font-size: 3em; background: blue; display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<!--Old Span-->
<div>ST<span id="one">A</span>CKOVERFLOW</div>
<!--New Span-->
<div>ST<span id="two">A</span>CKOVERFLOW</div>
<!--Original-->
<div>STACKOVERFLOW</div>
```

Comment: Great tip - I'll keep this in mind - may actually put a few negative margin utilities in the format superflycss package.