# Change specific character color in CSS writen textbox on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of 2 very specific characters when hovering it, in a textbox with content made purely in CSS.

Since it's not written in HTML but CSS, I can't specifically add style tags to do this and I'm lost.

What I want is the #CODESTUDENT:hover:after code to make the "<" & ">" red on hover.

```css
#CODESTUDENT:after {
  content: "CODE STUDENT";
}

#CODESTUDENT:hover:after {
  content: "<CODE STUDENT>";
}
```

```html
<li id="CODESTUDENT"></li>
```

I've tried adding color properties etc, I've not been able to fix this.

Comment: this is not possible, you can only set the color for the whole word. If you only need to set the style for < and > then you need to somehow seperate them from the rest of the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of one character in a text box HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css)

Comment: That isn't on hover, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mjb28t7d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add text to HTML (depends on your demands) add "CODE STUDENT" inside HTML's tag and use such styles:

```
#CODESTUDENT:hover::before {
  content: "<";
  color:red;
}

#CODESTUDENT{
  opacity:0;
}

#CODESTUDENT:hover{
  opacity:1;
}

#CODESTUDENT:hover:after {
  content: ">";
  color: red;
}
```

You can always remove styles for #CODESTUDENT and it'll remain on site.
https://codepen.io/ptr11dev/pen/dEOdxQ

Answer (score 2):

Can you use Javascript? If so, this would be a viable approach:

```js
for (const div of document.querySelectorAll('div')) {
  div.textContent = div.id;
}
```

```css
div::before,
div::after {
  color: red;
}
div:hover::before {
  content: "<";
}
div:hover::after {
  content: ">";
}
```

```html
<div id="CODESTUDENT"></div>
<div id="FOO"></div>
<div id="BAR"></div>
<div id="BAZ"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *hacky* idea where you can approximate this using the other pseudo element and playing with margin/letter-spacing.

```css
#CODESTUDENT:after {
  content: "CODE STUDENT";
}

#CODESTUDENT:hover:after {
  content: "CODE STUDENT";
  margin-left:-190px;
}
#CODESTUDENT:hover:before {
  content: "< >";
  letter-spacing:60px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<li id="CODESTUDENT"></li>
```

Another idea is to consider background coloration on the after element. Still hacky as you need to know the width taken by the `<` \ `>`

```css
#CODESTUDENT:after {
  content: "CODE STUDENT";
}

#CODESTUDENT:hover:after {
  content: "<CODE STUDENT>";
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left /10px 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(red,red) right/10px 100% no-repeat,
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<li id="CODESTUDENT"></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another **only CSS** solution: https://jsfiddle.net/wb34yzLh/1/

Essentially, we're constructing the word with the before pseudo class

```
 #CODESTUDENT::before {
   content: "CODE STUDENT";
   color: black;
 }
```

Then reconstruct the word on hover using before and after to be able to color letters individually.

```
 #CODESTUDENT:hover::before {
   content: "<CODE STUDENT";
 }

 #CODESTUDENT:hover::after {
   content: ">";
 }
```

Finally, we're coloring the only letter in after, i.e., > red. And the first letter on hover with the color red.

```
 #CODESTUDENT::after {
   color: red;
 }

#CODESTUDENT:hover::first-letter {
   color: red;
 }
```

Comment: You could generalize your solution with `content: attr(id);` and `content: "<"attr(id);`

Comment: @connexo what about the space in `CODE STUDENT`?

Answer (score 1):

I wholeheartedly agree with other answers and comments about using pseudo elements like they're meant to be used, but here's a wacky way to do this without touching your html:

```css
#CODESTUDENT:after {
      content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg height='30' width='200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ctext x='0' y='15' fill='none'%3E&lt;%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='15' y='15' fill='black'%3ECODE STUDENT%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='140' y='15' fill='none'%3E&gt;%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
    
  
#CODESTUDENT:hover:after {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg height='30' width='200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ctext x='0' y='15' fill='red'%3E&lt;%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='15' y='15' fill='black'%3ECODE STUDENT%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='140' y='15' fill='red'%3E&gt;%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      
    }
```

```html
<li id="CODESTUDENT"></li>
```

It works by swapping a svg data url on the hover selector, containing these svg's:

```
<svg height="30" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="none">&lt;</text>
  <text x="15" y="15" fill="black">CODE STUDENT</text>
  <text x="140" y="15" fill="none">&gt;</text>
</svg>

<svg height="30" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">&lt;</text>
  <text x="15" y="15" fill="black">CODE STUDENT</text>
  <text x="140" y="15" fill="red">&gt;</text>
</svg>
```

With some extra css it might even look bareable :).

Answer (score -1):

you can try as below to serve your purpose

html:

```
<li id="CODESTUDENT">CODESTUDENT</li>
```

css:

```
#CODESTUDENT:hover:before {
  content:"<";
  color:red;
}

#CODESTUDENT:hover:after{
  content:">";
  color:red;
}
```

Thanks