# i want to display the last letter # only in red color placeholder in angular

Tags: angular

i want to display the placeholder last letter # only in `red color` in angular

```
   <div class="col_xs-12 col_sm-6 col_md-6 col_lg-4 col_gt-lg-3 padding_8-16 pad_xs8-24">
            <md-input-container> 
                <input mdInput placeholder="{{'Others #'|translate}}" maxlength="75" id="txtOther" [(ngModel)]="this.NewCustomerModel.Other"
                    (keypress)="alphanumeric($event);"  >
            </md-input-container>
    </div>
```

i expect the output placeholder hash symbol `red color`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17341670/2050306