# How to highlight just one letter in a input element using css and vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css

inm trying to make basically a typing speed webpage.

So the user needs to type a sentence as fast as they can. But i want to check for any wrong letters in an input field. If its wrong, the letter should highlight red.

The thing is I dont know how to highlight just 1 letter in a input field element.

In case someone doesnt understand, lets say the user needs to copy the sentence below

`Hello World`

But they write: `Gello World`

It should highlight in red the `G` since its the wrong letter.

Comment: Im not sure if its possible to do that with an input element, however, if you make it a `contenteditable` div then surround the incorrect letter with a `span` element of color red that would work

Comment: How would you wrap one letter in a span though? I had thought of doing that but I dont know how to write that in code

Comment: Do you want to use a library or just pure javascript?

Comment: I just wqnt to use pure JS

Comment: Here is the same question and there are acceptable answers for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css

Comment: @KavinduPasanKavithilaka that isn't the same question, that one is asking how to change a character in which the answers are using pure html, this question is asking how to do it through javascript when the content editable is changed when not matching a string that can change