# How can I change color in javascript for each letter which has been written into an input if data attribute(HTML) === input text in javascript?

Tags: javascript

can you tell me please how can I change color (green is right, red is wrong) for each letter which has been written(in right order) into an input column if data attribute === input text **in Javascript?**

I mean if
data="word"
input value ="word" [image: example]

When I write w -  **letter** color is green else letter color red.

```
wo -stay green else red;
wor - green else red;
word -green else red;
```

My code is here:

```
let all = document.querySelectorAll('#input_Text')
all.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
    if(e.target.value === element.getAttribute('data-verb')){
    element.style.border = "5px solid green"
    
    }else{element.style.border = "5px solid red"};
    }));
```

Thx a lot

Comment: `querySelectorAll('#input_Text')` doesn't make sense because IDs have to be unique. `querySelector('#input_Text')` will do the trick. Or if you have lots of elements, use a class: `querySelectorAll('.input_Text')`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css

Comment: It's not possible to have multiple text colors in one `<input>` tag.

Comment: If its not possible. Can I use something like: element.addEventListener("input", function(event){console.log(event.target.value) but instead of console send it to some div above the input and there do whats in the picture I added into my question?
Or its better to do it in React, Vue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I've changed your `id` to `class` assuming there will be multiple inputs.
2. Also, use [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check if `data-verb` starts with current input value.
3. Use `element.style.border` to set the element border.

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll('.input_Text')
all.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
   var data = element.getAttribute('data-verb').toString();
   var value = e.target.value;
   if (e.target.value == ""){
    element.style.border = "none";
   }
   else if (data.startsWith(value)){
      element.style.border = "5px solid green";
   }
   else{
      element.style.border = "5px solid red";
   }
}));
```

```html
<input type='text' class='input_Text' data-verb="word">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all input elements `'input[data-verb]'` and attach an `input` event to set style border if the element's value [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) the entered text:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('input[data-verb]')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', ({ target: { value }}) => {
    const color = el.getAttribute('data-verb').startsWith(value) ? 'green' : 'red'
    el.style.border = `5px solid ${color}`
  }))
```

```html
<input type="text" data-verb="word">
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the same class to each input that you want to check a word for, then loop through the contents of `querySelectorAll`, adding an event listener to each of them.

Then you can use `includes` to see if the contents of what's typed matches the form's data attribute:

```js
let words = document.querySelectorAll('.word');

words.forEach((word) => {
  word.addEventListener('input', () => {
    
    if (word.dataset.verb.includes(word.value)) {
      word.style.border = '5px solid green';
    } else {
      word.style.border = '5px solid red';
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" data-verb="apple" class="word"><br />
<input type="text" data-verb="banana" class="word">
```